# AE Panel: Send obj from JS to JSX

Tags: javascript, jquery, extendscript, after-effects

I'm writing a panel for After Effects and am trying to send an Object from my main.js to my jsx file. From what samples I can find they say that I can't send an object but have to stringify() the obj and pass that instead.

I've tried sending both an object and a string of the stringify'd object - neither are working for me.

main.js

```
var profileUI = {
     script: '',
     data: {
          csv:    $('#csv')[0].checked,
          feed:   $('#json')[0].checked,
          gs:     $('#googleSheets')[0].checked
     },
}
var csInterface = new CSInterface();
csInterface.evalScript('$._ext_SB.batch("' + JSON.stringify(profileUI) + '"")' );
```

myFunctions.jsx

```
$._ext_SB={
    batch : function(profileUI) {

        var str = "";
        for (prop in profileUI) {
          str += prop + " [" + typeof profileUI[prop] + "]: " + profileUI[prop] + ".\n";
        }
        alert(str);
    },
};
```

I'm getting an error: Unable to run script at line 1. Expected: )

It doesn't seem to be getting an actual string and like I mentioned above , trying to pass an object doesn't work either (that would be preferable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues here. See:

### Syntax Error in JavaScript

You have an extra double quote (`"`) character in your call to `evalScript`. This:

```js
csInterface.evalScript('$._ext_SB.batch("' + JSON.stringify(profileUI) + '"")' );
```

should be this (note the removal of one of the two final `"` characters):

```js
csInterface.evalScript('$._ext_SB.batch("' + JSON.stringify(profileUI) + '")' );
```

### JSON Needs To Be Escaped

As you pointed out [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44188273/5285364), you need to escape the `"` characters in the JSON string such that it is properly un-escaped when processed by `evalScript()`. This results in:

```js
csInterface.evalScript('$._ext_SB.batch("' + JSON.stringify(profileUI).replace(/"/g,'\\"') + '")' );
```

For clarity, the escaping is accomplished using `.replace(/"/g,'\\"')`.

### `evalScript` Does Not Auto-Parse JSON

You will need to call `JSON.parse()` on your `profileUI` parameter to get the object version back. See:

```js
$._ext_SB={
    batch : function(_profileUI) {
        // Convert the input string back into an object.
        var profileUI = JSON.parse(_profileUI);

        // Everything else should work okay...
        var str = "";
        // ...
    }
}
```

Some notes:

1. The object you get back from `JSON.parse()` will be a simple Object - it will contain the same properties as the object you called `JSON.stringify()` on but it will not have any associated functions.
2. ExtendScript does not automatically provide JSON support. If it exists in the application when you start your panel, that is because all panels (including Adobe-built ones) share a single ExtendScript context. Some Adobe panels already include a JSON library and you can usually get away with using that. If you are not able to use JSON, however, you will need to include a compatible JSON library yourself. Some are mentioned [here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9134955#9134955).

Comment: I corrected the extra quote and added the JSON.parse(). I also added: #include "/Users/sbaden/Documents/development_AE/SCRIPTS/04_COMMON/json2.jsx"  but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Adjusted the writeup with your code! I just ran across the same issue recently and forgot to add it. Glad you were able to get everything sorted!

Answer (score 1):

On the js side, you can also use template strings:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

```
evalScript(`$._ext_SB.batch('${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(profileUI))}')`);
```

The single quotes contain the string to pass it as a string parameter to the jsx function.

And `encodeURIComponent` escapes everything a string could contain what might cause a problem when sending it to jsx.

Then, in jsx you reverse the encoding and stringification:

```
var profileUI = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(_profileUI));
```

`replace(/"/g,'\\"')` only replaces the double quotes which are generated by JSON.parse.

A string which could cause problems might also contain other special characters than double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code...

```
csInterface.evalScript('$._ext_SB.batch("' + JSON.stringify(profileUI) + '")' );
```

Needs to  change to:

```
csInterface.evalScript('$._ext_SB.batch("' + JSON.stringify(profileUI).replace(/"/g,'\\"') + '")' );
```

The JSON.stringify creates a valid string but when I try to create the source code for a string by `'"'+someString+'"'` this will only work if the someString itself does not contain any quotes. The replace() replaces all quotes with \" so that it can be sent as a valid string.